# How can I restore my iPhone 4s without getting the newest software?

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

Need to restore my 4s but cannot let it be upgraded to iOS 8 because iPhone 4s can't handle that new of an iOS.  I'm totally locked out of the phone (disabled) because my child tried to get into the passcode too many times.  :(

Can I get it restored without getting new software system?

Comment: Short answer, no, sorry.

Comment: How are you locked out?

Comment: If a kid is playing with the passcode screen, the iPhone starts putting increasingly longer delays. Eventually, the delay can get into years, which means you need to do a restore from iTunes to re-enable it.

Comment: "because iphone 4's can't handle that new of an ios."  Really?  Since when?  A quick google finds lots of users and reviews happy with a 4s on 8.3 example:  http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/04/09/ios-8-3-iphone-4s-reviews-should-you-install-ios-8-3/

Answer (score 1):

There are places online where people have kept the IPSW files, if you trust them not to have tampered with this then you could find the right one and when you are in iTunes Option/Alt + Click the Restore button and it will take that IPSW file.

I am not 100% sure if this will work because iOS has to check with the iTunes server and I am not sure if it will activate a phone on an old version... I think it will but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

iOS versions prior to the latest are not being signed by Apple any more. The IPSW file won't help you here with restoring with iTunes.